# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (101,2)

Tags: python, arrays, loops, sorting, iterator

I am trying to create a 3d tensor with the dimension (101, 2, 1000). I had to translate the R code I found to python and there is just a problem that r starts to iterate at 1 and python at zero.

Is there a way to solve this problem below?

Thanks in advance!

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 2), columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
a = np.array(df1)
a_stdnorm = stats.norm.ppf(a)
n_rows = a.shape[0]
n_cols = a.shape[1]
samples = 100
if samples % 2 == 0:
    samples = samples + 1 # force an odd number
samples_increment = samples - 1 # to cater for 1 based indices
tensor = np.zeros((samples, n_cols, n_rows))
    sum_col = a[:,0] + a[:,1]
    sort = np.argsort(sum_col)
    block_half = samples // 2
    start = 0
    end = start + samples_increment
    for n in range(n_rows):
        if (n + 1) - block_half > 0 and n + block_half <= n_rows:
            start = n - block_half
            end = start + samples_increment
        dx = sort[start:end]
        data = a_stdnorm[dx,:]
        tensor[:,:,sort[n]] = data

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-1b371b208d20> in <module>()
     22     dx = sort[start:end]
     23     all_data = a_stdnorm[dx,:]
---> 24     tensor[:,:,sort[n]] = all_data

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (101,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be a size mismatch. Specifically, `tensor` has slices of size `(101,2)` while `data` ends up having size `(100,2)`.

Removing these lines:

```
if samples % 2 == 0:
    samples = samples + 1 # force an odd number
```

And just making this line do nothing:

```
samples_increment = samples # to cater for 1 based indices (change #1)
```

Where we *don't* do anything to make the number of samples odd seems to do the trick.

---

If you do need the number of samples to be odd, you'll first need to change this line not to do anything again:

```
samples_increment = samples # to cater for 1 based indices
```

Then you'll find that at the last iteration, the loop will fail. This is because we round down when computing `block_half` because of the odd number of examples. As such, you'll have to do a bit of massaging to update `end` properly for this case.

Comment: Hey Victor! How would you make the samples turn to 101, so from iteration start from 0 until the full 100 not only until 99?

Comment: @MarvelousDamnit I think that we still don't need to `+ 1` to `samples_increment` since arrays are 0-based. The termination condition for the loop seems to be the remaining problem: flipping the `<=` to `<` seems to do the trick. (Because `end` will no longer overshoot the end of  `dx`, which was causing it to fetch only 100 elements instead of 101.)